Basis of topology on space of properly embedded smooth manifolds
In A Short Exposition of the Madsen-Weiss Theorem, Hatcher discusses (starting at p.6) a basis for a topology on the space $\mathcal{C}^n$, the space of all smooth oriented $d$-dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are properly embedded. The topology is defined to have as basis the sets $C(B,V)$, where

B is a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ centered at the origin.
V is an open set in the standard $C^\infty$-topology on the space of $d$-dimensional smooth compact submanifolds of $B$ that are properly embedded. Let's call this space $\text{Emb}_c^p(B)$.
Define $C(B,V) := \{ M \in \mathcal{C}^n \mid \text{$M$ intersects $\partial B$ transversely, } M \cap B \in V \}$.

Then Hatcher states that it is easy to show that, as $B$ and $V$ vary, these sets really define a basis, i.e. we have to show the following:

$\{ C(B,V) \}$ covers $\mathcal{C}^n$.
For every $C(B,V)$ and $C(B',V')$ and every manifold $M \in C(B,V) \cap C(B',V')$ there exist $B''$ and $V''$ such that $M \in C(B'',V'') \subseteq C(B,V) \cap C(B',V')$.

I believe I can show (1.), however I am having trouble showing (2.).
In order to show (2.), we simply need to choose suitable $B''$ and $V''$ such that the above holds. Wlog we can assume that $B \subseteq B'$, since all balls were centered at the origin. So my guess is that we choose $B'' := B$. However, I am unsure how to choose $V''$. If my understanding is correct, we cannot simply take $V'' := V \cap V'$, since $V$ is an open set in $\text{Emb}_c^p(B)$ and $V'$ an open set in $\text{Emb}_c^p(B')$, and I believe we can in general write
$$
\text{Emb}_c^p(B) = \bigsqcup_{S \in I_B} C^\infty(S,B)
$$
where $I_B$ is defined as the set $$\{ S \subseteq B \mid \text{$S$ smooth compact submfld., $S \cap \partial B = \partial S$, intersection is transverse} \},$$ so generally the intersection $V \cap V'$ is not well-defined.
However, I believe I can sort of fix this issue by viewing $V$ as sitting inside $\text{Emb}_c^p(B')$. If this works, it would only remain to show that $M \cap B' \in V' \implies M \cap B \in V'$, so long as $B \subseteq B'$. But again I seem to run aground with this approach. If need be, I can elaborate more on my work up to this point.
Perhaps there is a much more elementary proof, or I am simply misinterpreting some notions. I am grateful for any comments or hints!

I have not looked at that paper for a while so I don't recall the notation.  But if  you are interested in the various topologies on spaces of embeddings and submanifolds, perhaps look in Hirsch's Differential Topology textbook?  These topics are covered in enormous detail in that book.
